# Problem setup:upgrade with CSS

Tags: magento2, deploy

My Magento 2 not load CSS in frontend.

If I do `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, the problem is solved and load perfectly, but when I do `setup:upgrade,` CSS not load again.

I know that `setup:upgrade` remove the content **generated to CSS**.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, check your MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/static if it has the .htaccess file

Comment: It don't has .htaccess

Comment: That is the issue, try to search on google for the pub/static/.htaccess or upgrade your magento2 version if is not the latest

Comment: Thank you very much. I create the directory and run deploy to load css and if I change xml file and I run setup:upgrade, CSS is load. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also deploy the static content of your frontend locale.

```
php bin/magentosetup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Comment: Yes I run the command to my locale. The probem was .htaccess. Vlad Patru resolve my dubt

Answer (score 0):

First remove the file from pub/static folder and then run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magentosetup:upgrade
```

Comment: I do this but It's the same. It not load CSS good

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://magenticians.com/fix-broken-magento-2-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run `php bin/magentosetup:upgrade` command after that you have to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: But if I do a change in xml file, I nedd run php bin/magentosetup:upgrade

Comment: No you don't have to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after changes in xml files, you just have to run `php bin/magento cache:clean` if changes are not display.

Comment: @DipeshRangani you don't need to run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy after a setup upgrade, when you're in development mode.