# Magento 2.2.4: After 'setup:upgrade' command CSS do not load

Tags: css, cli, magento2.2.4

I am using PHP Version 7.1.11 with Magento 2.2.4.

Using `XAMPP` with `Windows 8.1`

Each time when use `setup:upgrade` command my CSS get lost and do not load.
Then I have to run `static-content:deploy` command.
Why this is happening each time, I am working in `developer` mode still this issue is coming.

I also have gone through some articles in stack overflow but they are not working for me. one of the article has the same issue but still that is not working for me.

[Problem setup:upgrade with CSS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151449/problem-setupupgrade-with-css/151456)

Need help in understanding the exact issue.

Thanks

Comment: have added your CSS in `pub/static/` folder and after `setup:upgrade` we must do static content deploy. Some time it is not working with developer mode.

Comment: @kunj, I am not working on `css`. i am just only running command `setup:upgrade`

Comment: basically, it works for me in developer mode. magento auto generates `pub/static` data but same not working for my one colleague with the same source and same configuration but he has not disabled cache from admin.

Comment: @kunj, yes Right, but it is not working for me, don't know what point I am missing , I am using windows xampp on localhost, and setup other versions of magento 2 , and still same issue is coming for me

Comment: Try after delete `pub/static/*` and do you have `.htaccess` in pub and static folder.

Comment: @kunj, I tried it, and the article which I have attached as link in my Question is suggesting the same to check for .htaccess file, it is already at right place

Comment: I had the same issue in windows xampp for Magento. I think this is Magento bug  not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78620/discussion-between-amit-game-and-kunj).

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands, it should fix.
Please replace `user` and `group` with your correct web user & group
Example, in ubuntu default: `user` = `www-data` & `group` = `www-data`
ie, `chown -R www-data:www-data .`

```
chown -R user:group .
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chown -R user:group .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```